# If Element lies in union of Prime ideals then...

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A'$ be an ideal in ring $A$ and a$\in A$( commutative ring with 1).

Let $ P_1 , P_2,...,P_r$ be prime ideals in $A$ such that $a+ A'\subseteq \bigcup P_1 \bigcup P_2 ... \bigcup P_r$.

(a) Then prove that the ideal $<a,A'> = Aa+A' \subseteq P_i$  for some $i\in \{ 1,...,r\}.$

(b) Prime avoidence lemma: Let $P_1 ,...,P_r$ be ideals in A such that almost two of them are not prime. If $A' \subseteq  P_1 \bigcup P_2,...\bigcup P_r$ , then prove that $A' \subseteq P_i$ for some $i\in \{1,...,r\}$.

For (a) I thought of assuming that that $<a,A'>$ is not subset of $P_i$  for any $i\in \{1,...,r\}$ in hope of of getting a contradiction. Some property of primes ideals is to be used but I am unable to think of it.

(b) In case every ideal is a prime ideal then I can use the (a) with $a=0$, but I am unable to think about the case when one ideal is not prime or two are not primes and will appreciate hints.

Can you please help?

Comment: Concerning (a): Assume it was not the case, then there exists some $x_i\in Aa+A' \not\subset P_i$ for all i, then multiply the $x_i$ and investigate the restulting element. Perhaps this helpfs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ideal contained in a finite union of prime ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016551/ideal-contained-in-a-finite-union-of-prime-ideals)

Comment: @cos_dm_math21 It only answers part (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induct on $r$. If $r=1$, then done.

Let $r=2$, then $A'\subset P_1\cup P_2.$ We can assume  $A'\nsubseteq P_1$ and $A'\nsubseteq P_2$. Let $x_1\in A'$ and $x_1\notin P_1$. Similarly $x_2\in A'$ and $x_2\notin P_2$. If $x_1\notin P_2$, we get a contradiction that $A'\subset P_1\cup P_2$. So we have $x_1\in P_2$. Similarly $x_2\in P_1.$  Then $x_1+x_2\in A'$, but $x_1+x_2\notin P_1\cup P_2$.

Next let $r\geq 3$. Now assume the statement for $r-1$. That is for any choice of $r-1$ ideals out of which atmost two of them are not prime ideals, then the result holds.

If $A'$ is contained in any of the $r-1$ many ideals out of $P_1,\dots, P_r$, then we are done by induction. So assume otherwise. We can safely assume that $P_r$ is a prime ideal.

Let $x\in A'$ such that $x\notin P_j$ for all $j=1,\cdots r-1$. Now if $x\notin P_r$ , then $x\notin \cup_{j=1}^r P_j$, a contradiction. So we can assume that $x\in P_r$.

Note $A'P_1\cdots P_{r-1}\nsubseteq P_r$, for otherwise either of the factors is contained in $P_r$, in that case we are done by induction. Let $y\in A'P_1\cdots P_{r-1}$ and $\notin P_r$. Now $x+y\in A'$, such that   $x+y\notin P_i$ for all $i.$

So we are done.