# An ideal belongs to union of Prime ideals then does it lies in any one of them?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have proved that if $P_1$ and $P_2$ are prime ideals and an ideal  I belongs to $P_1 \bigcup P_2$. Then $I\subseteq P_1$ or $I\subseteq P_2$.

> But I am not able to think how can I generalize it. ( I don't want to use induction so I didn't tried that). So, the problem is following: Let I be any ideal in a ring A such that $I\subseteq I_1 \bigcup I_2 \bigcup ... \bigcup I_n$, where each $I_i$  is prime ideal then show that $I \subseteq I_m$ for some $m\in$ {$1,...,n $}.

Please shed some light on how should I approach this.

Comment: You have to use induction...

Comment: These questions about Prime avoidance lemma have been asked and answered tons of times on this site: For example see https://math.stackexchange.com/users/161513/marc

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016551/ideal-contained-in-a-finite-union-of-prime-ideals

Comment: @EvansGambit Wrong link, maybe?